# Multiple DisplayMemberPaths in a CompositeCollection?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, compositecollection

I'm new to WPF. I have a StackPanel which contains multiple comboboxes with the ItemSource (set in the StackPanel's style) from a View (`CaSupplierColumns`) in SQL Server (Visual Studio created the link automatically which I dragged `ordersDataSet` from the Data Source panel). No problem with this.

Issue arises when I use `CompositeCollection` in order to add a custom value to one of the comboboxes (`Manufacturer`), all values show correctly and the added item appears too - but blank. The added item appears as a blank option in the combobox.

The culprit I discovered is the `DisplayMemberPath` set to `Columns` (which is the column header's name in the database view), when I set the `DisplayMemberPath` to null for this combobox, the added item appears indeed correctly, but the other values in the combobox appear as `System.Data.DataRowView`.

How can I have two different `DisplayMemberPath`s in one CompositeCollection? Or perhaps is there a different way to do it?

Here's my current XAML (stripped to leave the key parts):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:OrdersDataSet x:Key="ordersDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="caSupplierColumnsViewSource" Source="{Binding CaSupplierColumns, Source={StaticResource ordersDataSet}}" />
</Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Name="MapFields" DataContext="{StaticResource caSupplierColumnsViewSource}">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}" />
                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Columns" />
                <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Columns" />
                <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        ...

        <ComboBox Name="MfrPartNo" />
        ...

        <ComboBox Name="Manufacturer">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=caSupplierColumnsViewSource}}" />
                    <ListBoxItem>Another option</ListBoxItem>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do you want to show some fixed text like "Please choose ..." before the list of items ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create implicit DataTemplates for the various types in the collections, and I'd put them in that same `StackPanel.Resources` where you've got the implicit `ComboBox` Style. You'll have to get rid of the `DisplayMemberPath` attribute, because that'll prevent the implicit DataTemplates from being applied.

`DisplayMemberPath` isn't a very powerful feature; you switch to DataTemplates when the going gets weird. Throwing a heterogeneous bunch of stuff in a `ComboBox` is one of the cool things you can do with WPF, but you'll still have to do some work to get much use out of it.

`SelectedValuePath` is going to be of limited use here as well, for obvious reasons. You might have to start binding `SelectedItem` to a viewmodel property of type `Object` and doing some fiddling in the setter there.

```
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Columns" />
            <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Manufacturer}">
            <!-- I'm assuming Manufacturer has a Name property; change as needed -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate 
            xmlns:sysdata="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data"
            DataType="{x:Type sysdata:DataRowView}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Columns}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Etc. -->

    </StackPanel.Resources>
```